# Apply a customer birthday discount based on date custom field in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, date, woocommerce, user-data

Based on *[Only allow edit of custom field once per customer on My account > edit account in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65506084/only-allow-edit-of-custom-field-once-per-customer-on-my-account-edit-account-i)* answer to my previous question, I am trying to apply a customer birthday discount.

Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'give_birthday_discount', 10, 3 );
function give_birthday_discount( $cart, $user_id, $date = 'now' ) {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() && $date == get_user_meta( $user_id, 'birthday_field', true ) ) {
    
    $discount_percentage = 10;

    $cart->add_fee( __( 'Birthday Discount', 'woocommerce' ), -( $cart->subtotal * $discount_percentage / 100 ));
    }
}
```

But it gives me this fatal error:

> Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function give_birthday_discount()

So I need some help to apply a discount for customers birthday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$user_id` and `$date` are not arguments from the `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` action hook.

PHP functions used

- [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) - Format a local time/date
- d - Two-digit day of the month (with leading zeros) - 01 to 31
- m - Two digit representation of the month - 01 (for January) through 12 (for December)

---

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;
    
    // NOT logged in
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
        return;

    // Get current user id
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    
    // Get value
    $birthday = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'birthday_field', true );
    
    // NOT empty
    if ( ! empty( $birthday ) ) {
        // Convert
        $birthday = date( 'd.m', strtotime( $birthday ) );
        
        // Today
        $today = date( 'd.m' );

        // Compare, equal to
        if ( $birthday == $today ) {
            // Discount percentage
            $discount_percentage = 10;
            
            // Discount
            $cart->add_fee( __( 'Birthday Discount', 'woocommerce' ), - ( $cart->subtotal * $discount_percentage / 100 ), false );      
        }       
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'action_woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 10, 1 );
```